# Azure Devops structure for running a query on Azure SQL preferably via a Subscription

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

There is a rich API to manage Azure instances, servers, and security policies at   [az sql reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/sql?view=azure-cli-latest)  and [Azure CLI reference commands for Azure SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/azure-cli-reference-for-sql) .  But how can we simply connect to an existing *subscription* [or at least to a *connection string*] and run basic sql commands? I have not found an alternate API or any methods within these existing api's to do so.  Can one or more of the *admin*-focused methods be repurposed to run general queries / run general DML commands?

The preference would be to use an existing Azure-Subscription as the basis of the connectivity. In that way we do not need to access KeyVault for the server passwords [and URI's etc].

Comment: Backticks are for code/CLI snippets, not emphasis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [PowerShell Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell?view=powershell-7.3&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-6) and [Invoke-Sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps). It supports cross-platform: [Invoke-Sqlcmd is Now Available Supporting Cross-Platform](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/invoke-sqlcmd-is-now-available-supporting-cross-platform/). Check examples of connecting to Azure SQL: [Connect to Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps#example-11-connect-to-azure-sql-database-(or-managed-instance)-using-an-access-token). You may share query results through the logging commands: [About task.setvariable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell#about-tasksetvariable)

Setup [PowerShell@2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/powershell-v2?view=azure-pipelines) to use PowerShell Core:

> By default, PowerShell v2 uses PowerShell Core for Linux agents and
> Windows PowerShell for Windows agents. To use the latest version of
> PowerShell on Windows agents, set the pwsh parameter to true.
> PowerShell Core will then be used instead.

Comment: great info! I'm glad my question did not get closed [yet at least] to be able to read it! Not sure why so much disdain for this question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying out *Sqlcmd* and will embed it in a *Bash@3* task. Note it does work from *macOS* and *Linux*

ubuntu:

```
apt install -y install SqlCmd
```

```
Sqlcmd -S our-server.database.windows.net -d ourdb -G
```

Notice there are no passwords being shoved around here: the **-G** denotes to use *ActiveDirectory* behind the scenes with the logged-in user's credentials. This should translate as well to *Azure*

That brings up the *T-sql* prompt.  Then the *insert* statement we need can be invoked.

**Update**  On ADO the ActiveDirectory login is not found automatically. I will need to update this approach with the mechanisms to enable it.

The specific error message:

```
Failed to authenticate the user '' in Active Directory
(Authentication option is 'ActiveDirectoryIntegrated').
```

```
Running on Azure it does need login mechanics still:

commit;'

2023-04-04T08:34:50.8668817Z Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.

2023-04-04T08:34:50.8670276Z Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Failed to authenticate the user '' in Active Directory (Authentication option is 'ActiveDirectoryIntegrated').

2023-04-04T08:34:50.8671087Z Error code 0xA190; state 41360

2023-04-04T08:34:50.8671557Z Error acquiring Kerberos credentials

2023-04-04T08:34:50.8672027Z GSS status: No credentials were supplied, or the credentials were unavailable or inaccessible

2023-04-04T08:34:50.8672561Z Mechanism status: No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1001)

2023-04-04T08:34:50.8672954Z .

2023-04-04T08:34:50.8673556Z Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Timeout error [258]. .

2023-04-04T08:34:50.8676187Z Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Unable to complete login process due to delay in login response.

2023-04-04T08:34:50.8690776Z + script_out='OK
```